# Implementing jQuery Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm getting a list of notes from the database and displaying them to the view, if the note is less than 15 minutes old then I am displaying a edit button allowing users to inline edit the note and save the new information. I have this part working fully. I'm now trying to attach a timer to the notes that are less than 15 minutes old and hide the button when the timer is up. N.B. The user can edit multiple notes as long as they're < 15 minutes old. 
How would I go about doing this, as I'm not too familiar with jQuery and Javascript?
Thanks for any replies, as I'm quite new to this forum stuff I wan't sure if you needed code or not to answer the question. So if anyone wants to look at it I'll put it up.

Comment: In any case don't forget to do your server side validation on timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an .editable class to notes that are still editable and remove it when no longer.
You could retain the time for the note in a data-time="1359999066" attribute (assuming it's unix timestamp). Let me know if you need further help with the code I implied.

```
(function checkTimer() {
    $('.note.editable').each(function() {
        //check for timestamp, remove .editable and hide button
    });
    if ( $('.note.editable').length ) setTimeout(checkTimer, 5000);
})();
// this will check every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Your post has been great so far for this problem, thanks to your help I've been able to pass the expiration date through to the js.

Comment: Sorry, posted too early. Your post has been great so far for this problem, thanks to your help I've been able to pass the expiration date through to the js. I'm setting it by using strtotime() in php and passing it through via data-expiration. I am able to remove the id of the button which is hiding it. The problem I have came to now is that if there is more than one note it doesn't seem to work. The snippets of code that I'm using are as follows.

Comment: HTML - `{if $note.editable == 1}
                                <button class="greenBtn floatleft" id="edit-note" style="margin:10px 5px 5px 0;" name="edit-note" data-id="{$note.id}" data-expiration="{$note.expiry_time}"href="#">Edit</button>{/if}
                          </div>`

Comment: js for removing button - `window.setInterval(function(){

(function checkTimer() {
    $('#edit-note').each(function() {
        var expiration = $('#edit-note').data('expiration');
        now = new Date();
        if((now.getTime()/1000 > expiration))
          {
             $('#edit-note').remove();
          }
    });
    if ( $('.note.editable').length ) setTimeout(checkTimer, 5000);
})();
// this will check every 5 seconds

}, 5000);`

Comment: don't use ids, use classes, multiple elements can't have the same id value

Comment: and you don't need to wrap the js into the window.setInterval, just put it in the ready event (it's a self executing function that will call itself until there's no more editable elements)

Comment: Ok... I'll go back and fix that, thanks for the help so far. You've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Usage

```
    var timer = $.timer(function() {
            alert('This message was sent by a timer.');
    });

    timer.set({ time : 5000, autostart : true });

    timer.set(options);
    timer.play(reset);  // Boolean. Defaults to false.
    timer.pause();
    timer.stop();  // Pause and resets
    timer.toggle(reset);  // Boolean. Defaults to false.
    timer.once(time);  // Number. Defaults to 0.
    timer.isActive  // Returns true if timer is running
    timer.remaining // Remaining time when paused
```

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/

It might solve your problem..see full article and demo on link

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can attach an data attribute to each note containing the time of creation:

```
<div class="note" data-creation="1360000265027">
   <!-- milliseconds from 01.01.1970 (UTC) -->
   <p>My content</p>
   <button>edit</button>
</div>
```

Now you can check whether this is older than 15min:

```
(function checkTimer() {
     $('.note').each(function(){
         var creation = $(this).data('creation'),
              // time in milliseconds from 01.01.1970 (UTC) minus 15min (900000milsec)
              fifteenAgo = (new Date).getTime() - 9e5;
         if (creation <= fifteenAgo) {
              $(this).find('button').remove();
         }
    });
    if ( $('.note button').length ) setTimeout(checkTimer, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: time should be creation in the if clause

Comment: of course you are right... All the YYMMDDhhmm stuff is much to complicated anyway.

Comment: yes, we need a wrapper to check every x seconds! But maybe Annesley Cuttle found an own answer to this...